# Gui testing in PySide2 with qtbot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pyside2

I want to test my *Graphical User Interface* with the **qtbot** from pytest-qt.

I am new to testing in general and i could need some guidance on how to start writing these tests.

I want the bot to click on the file icon, then a QFileDialog opens, as in the picture below and the bot needs to select a pdf.

I already looked for documentation and what i found was not really helpful, i didn't understand how to set the qtbot up.

[image: QFileDialog]

Minimum Reproducibel Example:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication, QFileDialog


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.button = ''
        btn = QPushButton('Open File', self)
        btn.move(10, 10)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.open_file)
        self.resize(420, 450)

    def open_file(self):
        pdf_dialog_obj = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Open Pdf", "/Downloads", "Pdf Files (*.pdf)",)
        pdf_path = pdf_dialog_obj[0]
        print(pdf_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MW = MainWindow()
    MW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: I added a  minimal reproducible example.
Is the question clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know before, but now I know what to do.
Here's an example I wrote, you can refer to, mainly using monkeypatch to implement.

**main_window.py**

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication, QFileDialog


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton('Open File', self)
        self.button.move(10, 10)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.open_file)
        self.resize(420, 450)

    def open_file(self):
        filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Pdf", "", "Pdf Files (*.pdf)",)
        print(filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MW = MainWindow()
    MW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**test_button.py**

```py
import pytest
from PySide2 import QtCore

from src import main_window


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def creat_window(qtbot):
    main = main_window.MainWindow()
    qtbot.addWidget(main)
    main.show()
    qtbot.wait_for_window_shown(main)
    return main


def test_open_file(qtbot, creat_window):
    main = creat_window
    qtbot.mouseClick(main.button, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)
    # The code under replaces the :func:`QFileDialog.getOpenFileName` function by a ``lambda`` which always returns "file_path, file_type".
    file_path = r"/Downloads/test.pdf"
    file_type = 'Pdf Files (*.pdf)'
    monkeypatch.setattr(QFileDialog, "getOpenFileName", lambda *args: (file_path, file_type))
    ......
```